# Plot validation error and training error for Convolutional network in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, neural-network

Does anyone know how to plot validation error, for a conv net in Matlab? For vanilla neural net, there is a function called `plotperform`, but this does not work for conv nets.

Comment: Someone needs to read some papers!

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: You need to read scientific articles explaining how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no built-in function for CNN plotperform. What you can do is the following:

- Save your neural network performance using checkpoints parameter of training options

  ```
      options = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
      'MaxEpochs', 10, ...
      'InitialLearnRate', 1e-6, ...
      'CheckpointPath', 'models');
  ```

This will save a .mat file for each epoch.

- Use predict to create the training and validation accuracy points for
  your learning curve

You run the detect functon on your CNN to get the prediction:

`[bboxes, score, ~] = detect(cnn, testImage);`

Then depending on what kind of CNN you have, you need to come up with the accuracy benchmark. For classification problems, you could calculate the [F1 score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) for example.